# Can a Cartesian product of nonelements of Sigma Algebras be in the Product Sigma Algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, direct-product

If $F$ and $G$ are sigma algebras, then $F\times G$, i.e. the set of all Cartesian products of elements of $F$ and elements of $G$, is not a sigma algebra.  But it is possible to define a product sigma algebra of $F$ and $G$, namely by finding the sigma algebra generated by $F\times G$.  It consists of way more than just Cartesian products of elements of $F$ and $G$.

My question is, can the product sigma algebra of $F$ and $G$ contain a Cartesian product of two sets which are not elements of $F$ and $G$?  Can it contain the Cartesian product of an element of $F$ with a non-element of $G$, or vice verse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course if you take $A\times\emptyset$ or $\emptyset\times B$, they're equal to $\emptyset$ which is in the product $\sigma$-algebra $\pmb{F}\times \pmb G$even if $A\notin\pmb F$ or $B\notin\pmb G$.

However, assume $A\times B\in\pmb F\times \pmb G$ such that $A\neq \emptyset$ and $B\neq\emptyset$. Then we know the following:

> If $E$ is a measurable subset of $\pmb F\times \pmb G$, then every section of $E$ is measurable.

So take $x\in A$ (and that's where we use $A\neq\emptyset$). The  $x$-section of $A\times B$ is $B$. According to the proposition above, $B\in\pmb G$, and you can similarly find that $A\in\pmb F$.

Answer (score 1):

No. If $A \times B$ is in the product sigma algebra then $A$ and $B$ necessarily belong to the original sigma algebras. This is usually included in the proof of Fubini's Theorem where so-called sections of measurable sets are defined. The only exception is when  either $A$ or $B$ is empty.